# Get text from the pickerWidget in Titanium Alloy

Tags: titanium, titanium-alloy, titanium-widgets

I m trying to use a widget called [danielhanold.pickerWidget](https://github.com/danielhanold/danielhanold.pickerwidget)! By clicking on label the picker should popup and set the selected value as text on the label....i m a newbie to titanium and javascript so can anyone tell me how to get text of the selected value...

```
function selectcity (e) {
   Alloy.createWidget('danielhanold.pickerWidget', {
   id: 'mySingleColumn',
     outerView: $.win,
     hideNavBar: false,
     type: 'single-column',
     selectedValues: [20],
     pickerValues: [{10: 'Auburn', 20: 'Bald', 30: 'Black', 40: 'Blond', 50: 'Brown'}],
     onDone: function(e) {
       // Do something
     },
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved...

```
onDone : function(e) {
    $.label.text = e.data[0].value;
},
```